# Deleting newline from current line if next line is not a date

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a log file that looks would span multiple lines

```
01/02/18 19:01:01 some log some log
continuation of line 1 log
01/02/18 19:01:02 some log some log
01/02/18 19:01:03 some log some log
```

My question is, how can I remove new line from line 1, given that the next line(i.e. line 2) doesnt start with a timestamp. I've been looking at sed, but most of the solution just provide code, with very little explanation.

Comment: Show us what progress you've made so far. We can help you out further

Comment: yeah, you should always include the research effort you've made.. :)

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines (`s/old/new/`),that is all, so you're barking up the wrong tree by considering sed for this and should be looking into using awk instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^([0-9]{2}\/){2}/{if (p) print p; p=$0; next}
     p{p=p FS $0} END{print p}' file
```

```
01/02/18 19:01:01 some log some log continuation of line 1 log
01/02/18 19:01:02 some log some log
01/02/18 19:01:03 some log some log
```

**How it works:**

- `$1 ~ /^([0-9]{2}\/){2}` makes sure first field is a date field
- Inside first `{...}` we print buffer `p` if it is non-empty and move to next record
- Inside `p{...}` block we keep appending lines to buffer `p`. This block is executed for lines not starting with date field
- In the `END{...}` block we print last line.

Comment: This does work, but would you mind explaining the code?

Comment: I've added explanation

Answer (score 0):

another awk in the wold

```
awk '/^([0-9]+\/){2}[0-9]+/&&NR>1{printf( "\n")}{printf( "%s ", $0)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

```
sed -E ':A;N;/\n(([0-9 :/]){18})/{P;D;bA};y/\n/ /' infile
```